# How to bundle FinderSync Extension in an App built using py2app

Tags: macos, py2app, findersync

I'm trying to add a [FinderSync Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) in an App which is built using [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/).

py2app does not have a recipe for bundling App Extensions so I created a Cocoa project and added a FinderSync Extension target. After building the appex I copied the appex to the app built using py2app under Plugins folder.

The FinderSync Extension is set to be sandboxed using entitlement file but when I launch the main app I got following message displayed on Console App.

> 9/17/15 10:33:50.212 AM pkd[309]: ignoring mis-configured plug-in at
>   /Applications/Test.app/Contents/Plugins/TestFinderSync.appex: plug-ins
>   must be sandboxed

I've searched on Stack Overflow but could not find the solution.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your extension code signed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make it work You should provide the entitlements file from your plugin.

MyPlugin.entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And codesign the plugin with the your cert:

```
codesign --sign <cert> --entitlements <path to entitlements file> --force <path to bundle>/Contents/PlugIns/MyPlugin.appex
```

Also, if You are building the plugin from Swift source, make sure bundle up all required Swift*dylibs in Contents/Frameworks

Hope this helps